# System databases are in standby...how can I make them editable?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My System Databases are stuck in a standby/read-only state.

RESTORE DATABASE msdb WITH RECOVERY does not seem to have had any affect.

How can I get them out of the standby state?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This could be a lot of things.  Did your server crash?  Have you made any changes?

First of all, just for giggles:

```
dbcc checkdb (model)
dbcc checkdb (msdb)
```

If that checks out, check the ntfs permissions for the database files. Make sure SQL Server has access to them.

Also check the disk where the files live and make sure that it's healthy.  If the storage is RAID, check for failed drives or other less-than-optimal states.

Then, although you say you've done it:

```
restore database model with recovery
restore database msdb with recovery
alter database model online
alter database msdb online
```

You could also try restarting SQL Server.  I'm a little afraid that it might not come back if the problem is your storage, however, so I hesitate to recommend it.